# Minimal way to get HMAC SHA512 in swift 3.1

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm coding an app using xcode and `swift 3.1`

I need to create `hmac sha512` hash for my api call to the server.

I konw there are various frameworks like `CryptoSwift` that provide us with such feature.

However I am interested to know if it's possible in native `xcode / swift 3.1` without the use of any libraries or frameworks.

If not then why not?

Also, if I do need to use the library, what's the minimal method to get `hmac sha512` based library code only?

Thanks.

Comment: Sure it's possible. It's just math. Look up the algorithm and write it. :)

Comment: Or pull it out of CryptoSwift, which includes SHA-512 in Swift without a framework underneath it. https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift/blob/master/Sources/CryptoSwift/SHA2.swift

Answer (score 3):

You should definitely use CommonCrypto because it is already available on every device, well tested and fast. You just need to add a bridging header containing

```
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h>
```

You can look up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift) how to add the bridging header.

You then can compute your HMAC with a simple extension (Swift 4):

```
extension String {

    func hmac(key: String) -> String {
        var digest = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH))
        CCHmac(CCHmacAlgorithm(kCCHmacAlgSHA256), key, key.count, self, self.count, &digest)
        let data = Data(bytes: digest)
        return data.map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }.joined()
    }

}
```

Example:

```
let result = "test".hmac(key: "test")
```

Result:

```
88cd2108b5347d973cf39cdf9053d7dd42704876d8c9a9bd8e2d168259d3ddf7
```